# How to get the total count of items before ng-infinite-scoll runs in angular js?

Tags: angularjs

I get count of only those items that appears in the window screen but on 
scroll the count increases

```html
<p>@{{data.length}} <p>

<div infinite-scroll="loadMore()" infinite-scroll-distance="2">

<div  class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4" ng-repeat="item in data=(product_data|limitTo:numberToDisplay) track by $index">
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you have another result set property called let say data.totalCount when querying the database. So now you will have 2 result sets from your db query: one that shows total number of items in your table and one that you use to populate array of models on frontend.